# Library for encoding wav to aac on linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, wav, aac

I am trying to find a wav to aac encoder to convert my wav files to aac. The catch is that I need to use it in a commercial setting (not distribution, just usage). Does anybody know of a good one? I am still googling around but there are complaints about quality on some of them, so I was wondering if anybody had a good experience with one. Thank you!

Comment: You're probably going to have to buckle down and pay for Nero's.

Comment: Noooooooo, there is really no decent open source alternative? I tried ffmpeg to no avail, as I am getting some errors regarding bit rate and such.

Comment: FFMPEG's is incomplete, and FAAC is little more than a proof of concept.

Comment: I would say that this question has little todo with the shell.

Comment: In my opinion it does as there are several converters that can be used on Windows and Mac due to the popularity of iTunes, but not any I have found that can be used on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into other open source solutions, Nero AAC codec seemed to be the best quality wise. However, I was never able to get into contact with their licensing department, so ended up using MP3 encoding instead.